# VLOOKUP and Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I'm using Google Sheets right now and trying to create a spreadsheet and for some reason every value seems to work fine with my VLOOKUP formula except for `Hunter`. For whatever reason it's saying it cannot find the value within the range! I triple checked spelling, ensured no extra spaces and it's still not finding the value.

**FORMULA:**

```
=VLOOKUP($K$2,BackgroundData!$C$2:$H$4,2)
//the index increments each line down; starting at 2 and ending at 5
```

**IMAGES OF ERROR**

[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/En4at.png)

[Perfectly fine VLOOKUP](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CXnwv.png)

[Spreadsheet where data is being pulled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fugFp.png)

I also tested changing the `Hunter` name to `Test` and then it works fine, but going back to `Hunter` it does not work.

Any idea why this is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the issue to this...

I was missing the `False` flag at the end of the `VLOOKUP()`, indicating whether the data is in order or not.

```
=VLOOKUP($K$2,BackgroundData!$C$2:$H$4,2,FALSE)
```

Comment: You can also use `0` instead of `FALSE`